# MariaDB SELECT with index used but looks like table scan

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a MariaDB 10.4 with a hung table (about 100 million rows) for storing crawled posts. The table contains 4x columns, and one of them is `lastUpadate` (datetime) and indexed.

Recently I try to select posts by lastUpdate. Most of them returns fast with index used, but some takes minutes with fewer records returned and looks like a table scan.

This is the query explain without conditions.

```
> explain select 1 from SourceAttr;
+------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | SourceAttr | index | NULL          | idxCreateDate | 5       | NULL | 79830491 | Using index |
+------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
```

This is the query explain and number of rows returned for the slow one. The number of `rows` in the explain is almost equals to the above one.

```
> select 1 from SourceAttr where (lastUpdate >= '2020-01-11 11:46:37' AND lastUpdate < '2020-01-12 11:46:37');
+------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra                    |
+------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | SourceAttr | index | idxLastUpdate | idxLastUpdate | 5       | NULL | 79827437 | Using where; Using index |
+------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+----------+--------------------------+

> select 1 from SourceAttr where (lastUpdate >= '2020-01-11 11:46:37' AND lastUpdate < '2020-01-12 11:46:37');
394454 rows in set (14 min 40.908 sec)
```

The is the fast one.

```
> explain select 1 from SourceAttr where (lastUpdate >= '2020-01-15 11:46:37' AND lastUpdate < '2020-01-16 11:46:37');
+------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                    |
+------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | SourceAttr | range | idxLastUpdate | idxLastUpdate | 5       | NULL | 3699041 | Using where; Using index |
+------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+

> select 1 from SourceAttr where (lastUpdate >= '2020-01-15 11:46:37' AND lastUpdate < '2020-01-16 11:46:37');
1352552 rows in set (2.982 sec)
```

Any reason what might cause this ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why would it chose type `index` for the one and type `range` for the other query? That's strange. Can you check with `BETWEEN` instead of two comparisons and `AND`?

Comment: @Zrin Nothing changed.

Comment: what happens if you narrow the time range in the last query, e.g. `select 1 from SourceAttr where (lastUpdate >= '2020-01-15 11:46:37' AND lastUpdate < '2020-01-15 23:46:37')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you see `type: index` it's called an **index scan**. This is almost as bad as a table-scan.

Notice the `rows: 79827437` in the EXPLAIN of the two slow queries. This means it's examining over 79 million items in the scanned index, either `idxCreateDate` or `idxLastUpdate`. So it's basically examining every index entry, which takes nearly as long as examining every row of the table.

Whereas the quick query says `rows: 3699041` so it's estimating less than 3.7 million rows examined. More than 20x fewer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I miss the `type: index`. Is there any reason why the slow query returns fewer rows with `type: index` while the quick one returns more rows with `type: range` ?

Comment: They're different queries, searching for rows in different time ranges. Is it not expected that they would have different result sets?

Comment: @BillKarwin, it is not expected / clear that they would be carried out in a different way, that the optimizer would treat them differently just because the constants are different.

Comment: But you asked why they return a different number of rows. That has nothing to do with the optimizer's choice, it has to do with how many rows exist in the table matching two different date ranges.